# Openshift root folder without rhc committing

Tags: php, shell, openshift, paas

I am trying to use openshift to host one of my php sites.

I created an application then I can access as **my-site.rhcloud.com** with its default configuration that is an index.php file.

I have noticed the document root described in its instruction [Setting Your Document Root](https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-getting-started.html#set-document-root).

```
IF php/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=php/
ELSE IF public/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=public/
ELSE IF public_html/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=public_html/
ELSE IF web/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=web/
ELSE IF www/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=www/
ELSE DocumentRoot=/
```

But even I follow its naming convention to create a **web** folder there, and put the files those work correctly locally into it, I can not access it as **my-site.rhcloud.com** but display bellow error.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

BTW, I don't use the rhc committing way as usual but just fetch my files from bitbucket git.

So how could I make my site folder as root, please?

Comment: Can ssh into your app and check that your index.php (and the rest) is indeed located in `~/app-root/repo/web/` and `~/app-root/runtime/repo/web/`? If it's not there, there may be a problem in the way how you're pushing the files there.

Comment: @JiriFiala Yes, I use putty to ssh into my app, and the index.php exists the right place.

Comment: I would then check logs in `~/app-root/logs/` for details on why the files are not served. You should see there and exact path to a file that cannot be served (e.g. `File does not exist: /var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/app-root/runtime/repo/web/index.html`) with the GET request.

Comment: Do you have any of the other directories or just the `web` directory? It could be a problem if you have any of the `php`, `public` or `public_html` directories

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves Yes, I have the only **web** directory there. By default, there is just the **index.php**file, so I delete it and cp my files into web directory.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by using bellow command:

```
ln -s <my webroot path> web
```

That's all;)

Good luck to those who have encountered this issue.